# Appcompat Action bar Icon background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have a custom theme for my appcompat action bar, however the action icons (back icon and overflow menu buttons) are black but I am using the  `android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_sys_upload"` and the background for this is staying white and I want this to be black.

Below is my theme code;

```
 <style name="Theme.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Alcontrol</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_alcontrol</item>
   <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_alcontrol</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_alcontrol</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Alcontrol" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_alcontrol</item>
</style>
```

Comment: set theme for values-v14,values-v11 also

Comment: Maybe you want Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar? @user2029541

Comment: No I don't want a dark action bar. it has be light, (set to a light grey).  Or are you saying I just need to the theme name but leave everything else?

Comment: It would be help full if you post screen shot of your problem @user2029541